# Concat/Join Multiple SAML attributes for Claim Rules for ADFS

Tags: concatenation, saml, adfs, rules

Figured I would post this here for posterity, as I was unable to find exact steps, but parsed it together for this unique use case. Hope it'll help someone else's struggle.

We have a 3rd party using our ADFS to gather some details like Job, Title, etc.

**Problem**
However, the upper management wanted to know if it was possible to change a "Display Name" property in the 3rd party to a combination of other fields stored in AD.

We're already were passing these in the current rule:
[Given-Name(URN:OID:2.5.4.42),
Surname(URN:OID:2.5.4.4),
Title,
Department](https://i.stack.imgur.com/622Br.png)

Needed to add a

> Display Name = First Last, Title

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional Rule
Type: Send Claims Using a Custom Rule

```
c1:[Type == "urn:oid:2.5.4.42"]
 && c2:[Type == "urn:oid:2.5.4.4"]
 && c3:[Type == "Title"]
 => issue(Type = "Display Name", Value = c1.Value + " " + c2.Value + ", " + c3.Value);
```